# Mass action doesn't work for Magento backend grid serializer

Tags: php, magento, backend

I've created a grid inside the tab using grid serializer using [this tutorial](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/07/magento-grid-serializer-admin-tabs-grid/). Then I've added a massaction to this grid using [this tutorial](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-massactions-to-magentos-grid/).

Mass action block has appeared, but when I choose entities, choose massaction and click Submit, following error has been thrown to browser's console:

```
"ReferenceError: {gridId}_massactionJsObject is not defined"
```

Have anybody ever tried to add a mass action to the grid inside the tab? How to solve this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of removing var in the abstract class just set the object to the window.

in app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml calls out to getAdditionalJavascript()

In your grid file add this function.

```
protected function getAdditionalJavascript() {
    return 'window.{gridId}_massactionJsObject = {gridId}_massactionJsObject;';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just attempted this today and ran into the same problem on Magento CE 1.8. After some digging, A co-worker and I discovered that the JavaScript in *grid.phtml* (lines 207-224) was running but not showing up in the DOM (still not sure why). When using the console, we noticed the `varienGrid` object is accessible because it is global due to being defined without a `var`.

With that being said, we found the mass action js in *Abstract.php* in the function `getJavascript()` (line 225) and removed the `var` from the variable definition. This solved the problem for us and hopefully will help you out. Also, you should not modify core. The file should be copied to local and modified there.

**grid.phtml** - *app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml*

**Abstract.php** - *app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Massaction/Abstract.php*